# Two identity range constraints on subscriber table - SQL Server replication

Tags: sql-server, constraints, database-replication

We have transactional replication with updatable subscriptions. At subscriber have have several tables with double identity constraint. (Not sure how to replicate this. Maybe it happened during one of reinitializations on re-creations of the replication)
For instance:

```
CHECK NOT FOR REPLICATION (([ID]>(513000) AND [ID]<(514000)))
CHECK NOT FOR REPLICATION (([ID]>(347934) AND [ID]<(360000)))
```

DBCC CHECKIDENT result:

```
Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL', current column value '538185'.
```

Replication works as intended, but we want to get rid from the excessive constraint. Have no idea why current identity is NULL here. I know that we can reseed the ident so it would become within the range, but how to determine which from 2 constraints is valid and actual for replication?
For some tables it is not an issue and current ident is within one of 2 ranges, but here goes another question: how can we safely remove excessive constraint?

I believe we could remove the article from the replication, verify all constraints are removed from table, then put article back and reinitialize all subscriptions. But reinitializing isn't really good solution for us, because it would take too much time and it may harm our customers.

If we would try just to delete one of constraints - would it do any harm to the replication? Is information about constraints saved in some system tables which can cause troubles in future?

Any ideas about neat solution?

Comment: The identity is `NULL` because no inserts have been done relying on the identity -- replication (normally) replicates the original value, so it explicitly supplies a value. This is also why the actual identity value on the subscriber normally does not matter. However, the constraints are curious because if both are enabled, inserts are not possible at all -- the ranges have no overlap so all values of `ID` would trip one or the other. I would suspect one or both constraints are actually disabled, or else no inserts are actually taking place for this subscriber.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good point, but actually values are replicated correctly. I believe CHECK >NOT< FOR REPLICATION does the thing. If we would insert manually, it would break, but these constraints are ignored when data manipulation is done by replication agents. And I don't see that any constraint would be disabled.

Comment: Right, that always confuses me -- I always think `NOT FOR REPLICATION` means "replication will skip (replicating) this", but it means "this will be replicated, but the replication mechanisms will be allowed to ignore it". In any case I don't see why the constraints should then bother you at all, since they effectively don't do anything. You can certainly delete them with impunity, in the sense that nothing can break. (Replication does not check or care if the replicated table's definition matches after initialization, as long as the DML statements work.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert is there any article to which I can refer to ensure replication doesn't care about table's definition? From what I've seen, it stores a lot of info in system tables, so we wonder if that wouldn't cause troubles in future.

Comment: Not that I know of. I can only draw on a few years of experience with it, but that's not written down.